# How to create a select input, which returns either sql data or manually typed data?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i've created a php select input, which returns sql data:

```
//index.php
<label>Plate</label>
<select name="plate" class="form-control action" id="plate" data-live-search="true"  title="select plate"></select>

.....
..

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).on('submit', '#user_form', function(event){
 $('#plate').selectpicker();

function load_data(type)
{
    $.ajax({
    url:"actions/visits/load_data.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{type:type},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
    var html = '';
    if(type == 'plate_data')
    {
        for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
    {
        html += '<option value="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].name+'</option>';
    }
        $('#plate').html(html);
        $('#plate').selectpicker('refresh');
    }
    }
    })
}
 </script>
```

The load_data function calls load_data.php, which returns mysql data as follows:

```
//load_data.php
if($_POST["type"] == "plate_data"){
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM vehicles
    ORDER BY plate ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $data = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
       $output[] = array(
       'id' => $row["plate"],
       'name'  => $row["plate"].' || '.$row["make"]
       );
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
   }
```

Any idea, on how to select either data from vehicles or type myown in same select input form? Can this idea work?

Comment: A `<select` only lets you select pre-set options. You could have an "other" category and then a textbox which appears when that option is selected. Or there are no doubt JS plugins which can make something which looks like a select but also has free-text options. Have you done any research?

Comment: You could put a `<select>` with the information you have, and an extra option "Other".  When "Other" is selected, show a text field for input.

Comment: I've done this, but i'm wondering if i could combine them in a select box